# How to order by column with two level in SQL?

Tags: sql, select, sql-order-by

I need to write a SQL statement to select and sort data ordered by priority of value and name. Please see the criteria below.

Database schema :

```
    name : string
    isSpecial : boolean
    isA1 : boolean
    isA2 : boolean
    isA3 : boolean
```

Order Priority (The priority of isA1, isA2, isA3 are equal, I want to order from the number of true of isAx)

- isSpecial
- 3A (All isA are true)
- 2A (Two of isA are true)
- 1A (only one of isA is true)
- Second level ordered by : name

example

```
id, name, isSpecial, isA1, isA2, isA3
1, aaa, false, true, true, true
2, bbb, true, true, true, true
3, ccc, false, false, false, true
4, hhh, false, true, false, true
5, ddd, false, true, true, false
```

expected order is

```
2 (isSpecial = true)
1 (3A)
5 (2A, name = ddd)
4 (2A, name = hhh)
3 (1A)
```

Do you have any idea or any suggestion?

**Update**
Please see the SQL statement from the comment below.

Comment: First, learn what RDBMS you are using; SQL Server and Oracle are 2 completely different (and competing) products. Then retag the correct one, and *only* that one. As for your question, what's wrong with an `ORDER BY` here? Have you tried to implement one? If not, why not? If you have, why didn't your attempt(s) work? What *were* your attempts?

Comment: @Larnu Thank you for your edit. I have tried to create an SQL statement. Please see my update above.

Comment: `name` is in your `ORDER BY` 5 times; that doesn't make much sense. If you've already ordered by `name`, ordering by it again isn't going to change the sort order.

Comment: Having multiple columns containing the same "type" of data such that you end up with numeric suffixes (as your isA1, isA2, isA3 columns appear to be here) is usually a mistake. It usually indicates that the data should have been modelled in a table with one column and *multiple* rows (which also makes it trivial to accommodate the fourth instance, when it appears, rather than having to change the schema again)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thank you for your suggestion. The numeric suffix is for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need three terms in the order by clause - isSpecial, the number of "isA" truths and the name. Assuming your database treats false and true as 0 and 1, I'd do something like this:

```sql
SELECT   *
FROM     docs
ORDER BY isSpecial DESC,
         isA1 + isA2 + isA3 DESC,
         name ASC
```

If your database can't implicitly convert booleans to ints like this, you'll have to replace the isA columns with case expressions that perform this logic before summing them.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked for me. I think too complicated.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name won't a chain a of `or`s return `true` if any of them are `true`? It seems like you'd lose the destinciton between one, two or three of them being `true`, won't you?